# Taking pictures with a small Arduino

Tags: arduino-leonardo

I'm trying to make a time lapse video of a crystal patch in a small space.  I need some way of taking a picture every hour or so within an area no greater than 35mm, the smaller the better.  Something like the Arduino-Leonardo-Beetle would be the ideal dimensions.  What sort of camera and Arduino board do people recommend?  Thanks!

Comment: While not entirely impossible, an Arduino is not suited to this, something already explained to you when you asked this on EESE: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312692/arduino-beetle-and-camera

Comment: I'm just looking for a second opinion.  You've told me on two different boards that it isn't entirely impossible, but both times you haven't offered any suggestions on how to go about it in the (admittedly small) realm of what is possible.  I don't intend to sound rude, but if you insist on following me from board to board to comment on how it isn't entirely impossible, would you kindly at least offer some advice on _how_ to perform this operation instead of just saying it wouldn't be your top choice of doing it and downvoting me?

Comment: I didn't downvote your *original* posting, someone else did.  And I already mentioned buffered cameras but that even with that the lack of memory on an Arduino still makes things very challenging.  You are wasting your time and money to pursue this with an Arduino.

Comment: Many digital cameras, and even some motorized analog cameras, can be triggered by a wired remote. You can replace the remote by a relay, and have the Arduino drive the relay through some sort of transistor.

Comment: Sounds like the issue is space. Can you use a camera like [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/) connected to a RPi? The ribbon cable allows you to place the RPi outside the container (I assume the crystals are in some type of enclosure). With the RPi, you would probably not even need any coding.

Comment: Yeah @Johnny, this ought to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Arducam](http://www.arducam.com/tag/arducam-rev-c/). I have used it and the library is maintained.